# javascript: regexp to match a word that is NOT enclosed in custom tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match and replace all occurrences of 'word' that are not enclosed within the tags `:$` and `$:` in a string. There may be other characters within the tags beside 'word'.

So, say I have the string

`abc word hey :$ my word $:`

And I need to replace `word` with `letter`; Essentially I want to obtain the following string:

`abc letter hey :$ my word $:`

What is the best way to achieve that in JavaScript?

Further information:

tags won't be nested.
the string may contain the characters ':' and '$' singularly. In this case they should be treated as simple characters and not as a tag.

Comment: What is the way you have tried? What went wrong? Can you post a live demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Just FYI, `Javascript` and `Java` are not related, so don't tag `Javascript` questions with `Java`.

Comment: This will be quite hard with regex. Better you write a small parser.

Comment: Can tags be nested, like `lorem :$ ipsum dolor :$ sit $: amet $:`?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Comment: +1 for editing the question to add the asked-for info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to specify a RegExp for that, so here is a more imperative approach that does this - http://jsfiddle.net/dNhLm/

```
var text = "abc word hey :$ my word $:";
var replace = function(text, pattern, replacement) {
  var parts = [];
  // This will split the string into parts. The ones that has :$ we will have to proceed further and ignore
  var splitByEnd = text.split('$:');    
  for (i = 0, l = splitByEnd.length; i < l; i++) {
      // Here we should have at most 2 parts. The left one will be outside of the :$,$: pairs and is the
      // one we will apply the replacement. The right one if present will be between the :$,$: pairs and is
      // not a subject of replacement.
      var splitByStart = splitByEnd[i].split(':$');
      splitByStart[0] = splitByStart[0].replace(pattern, replacement);

      parts.push(splitByStart.join(':$'));
  }

  return parts.join('$:');
}

alert(replace(text, 'word', 'letter'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. I should have mentioned that there may be multiple occurrences of the tag pairs, and some may not even contain 'word'. It looks like your code works only if there is a single tag pair.

Comment: @user3173481 Actually I have written in exactly with the expectation that you will have multiple :$,$: pairs. I have just checked with a more complex string and it works - http://jsfiddle.net/dNhLm/1/

There is the assumption that you don't have nested tags.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, also works with multiple :$,$: pairs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure regex is the right tool for the job here (a parser is likely more appropriate), but I guess one simple solution would be to cut out the bits covered by the tags, replacing all words, then replacing the tags. Something along the lines of this (which won't support nested tags, but should otherwise work):

```
var line = 'abc word hey :$ my word $: word :$ my word $:';
var tags = [];
var index = 0;
while (line.match(/:\$.*\$:/)) {
    var start = line.indexOf(':$');
    var end = line.indexOf('$:', start);
    var tag = line.substring(start, end + 2);
    line = line.replace(tag, '$tag' + index + '$');
    tags.push(tag);
    index++;
}
line = line.replace(/word/g, 'letter');
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    line = line.replace('$tag' + i + '$', tags[i]);
}
document.write('result ' + line)
```

This outputs:

```
result abc letter hey :$ my word $: letter :$ my word $:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(.+?)?(:\$.+?\$:)(.+?)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This will give you three capturing groups:

1. Everything before `:?` and `?:`
2. The content inbetween your custom tags
3. Everything after `:?` and `?:`

You then want to do an usual stringreplace on the first and third capturing group, replacing `word` with `letter`.

The first and third group are optional, to `:?word?: another word` will match, too.

```
var regex = /^(.+?)?(:\$.+?\$:)(.+?)?$/i;
regex.exec('abc word hey :$ my word $:');  
alert(RegExp.$1.replace("word", "letter") + RegExp.$2 + RegExp.$3.replace("word", "letter"));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vq8M6/)
[Demo@debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/1v5JT3OtwicLwkt3)

Comment: Interesting approach but it doesn't cope with multiple tags.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy regular expression, I can think of.

You can look for multiple regular expressions instead

```js
var s1 = 'abc word hey :$ my word $: def word :$ another word $: word ghi :$ a third word $: jkl word';
var s2;

// word at the beginning
s2 = s1.replace(/^([^:$]*)word/, '$1letter');
// word at the end
s2 = s1.replace(/word([^:$]*)$/, 'letter$1');
// and word in between
s2 = s1.replace(/(:[^$]*)word([^$]*:)/g, '$1letter$2');
console.log(s2);
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n93AJ/)

Comment: Shouldn't the `$` be escaped in the regex?

Comment: @Thor84no The `$` is inside a character set, so it is not needed. You can see, that it works in the JSFiddle.